# Typeorm/Nestjs Raw query usage forcing lowercase to column name

Tags: sql, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I need a help on executing a query using nest/typeorm;

Im using Typeorm "InjectConnection" to build a raw query into my Postgres Database, the field giving me the error is the column user_roles_role.userId (note that I from userId is uppercase)
Heres the code:

```
const queryText = `SELECT * FROM user_roles_role WHERE user_roles_role.userId = ${id}`

try {
  const rawData = await this.connection.query(queryText);
  return rawData;
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  return err;
}
```

I get an error while doing this query, because somehow Typeorm is forcing lowercase on the column name, as seen below on typeorm error (from catch(Err))

> query: 'SELECT * FROM user_roles_role WHERE user_roles_role.userId =
> 1',   parameters: undefined,   driverError: error: column
> user_roles_role.userid does not exist

I've tried:

Using single quotes and double quotes (didn't work)

Full Error:

> "query": "SELECT * FROM user_roles_role WHERE user_roles_role.userId = 1",
> "driverError": {
> "length": 189,
> "name": "error",
> "severity": "ERROR",
> "code": "42703",
> "hint": "Perhaps you meant to reference the column >"user_roles_role.userId".",
> "position": "37",
> "file": "parse_relation.c",
> "line": "3599",
> "routine": "errorMissingColumn"
> }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As PostgreSQL sensitive case, you should make the column on double quotes like this:

```
 `SELECT * FROM user_roles_role WHERE user_roles_role."userId" = ${id}`
```

Comment: Does not work, when I do this I get the following error: query: 'SELECT * FROM user_roles_role WHERE "user_roles_role.userId" = 1',
  parameters: undefined,
  driverError: error: column "user_roles_role.userId" does not exist,  looks like Its a typeorm issue

Comment: SELECT * FROM user_roles_role where user_roles_role."userId" = 1 worked, Ill accept the answer cuz it led me to this solution, thank you

Comment: yes you are right we should to the quotes only for the column, I'll update my answer for the others who need the solution, you're welcome